# How to modify origninal array using map and filter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object of this structure

```
const values = {
    containerName: "test",
    models: [
        {
            modelName: "1",
            modelType: "DecisionTreeClassification",
            parameters: [empty, 1, 1]
        },
        {
            modelName: "2",
            modelType: "DecisionTreeClassification",
            parameters: [empty, empty, 2, 2]
        }
    ]
    numberOfSteps: "1"
}
```

I want to remove all the empty items from my parameters array.

I wanna do something like this

```
values.models.map(model => model.parameters.filter(param => param))
```

But instead of returning a new array to me I want it to modify my original array.

I want my final result to be this

```
const values = {
    containerName: "test",
    models: [
        {
            modelName: "1",
            modelType: "DecisionTreeClassification",
            parameters: [1, 1]
        },
        {
            modelName: "2",
            modelType: "DecisionTreeClassification",
            parameters: [2, 2]
        }
    ]
    numberOfSteps: "1"
}
```

Comment: What’s the reason you need to modify the original array? Map/filter will always return a new array - you could use forEach to iterate over the arrays and mutate them as needed.

Comment: This array is a part of a form. These empty values are an unwanted side-effect that I'd like to get rid off before storing it in my db.

Comment: Why can’t you just pass the new array to the db?

Comment: The object is in the same structure as the NoSQL db. Thus if it's modified we could just send one single post request instead of writing code to handle it in the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if you really want to mutate , you can use foreach
```

```js
const values = {
    containerName: "test",
    models: [
        {
            modelName: "1",
            modelType: "DecisionTreeClassification",
            parameters: ['', 1, 1]
        },
        {
            modelName: "2",
            modelType: "DecisionTreeClassification",
            parameters: ['', '', 2, 2]
        }
    ],
    numberOfSteps: "1"
};

values.models.forEach((mod) => {
    mod.parameters =  mod.parameters.filter(parameter=>parameter)
    
 });

console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const val = {
    containerName: "test",
    models: [
        {
            modelName: "1",
            modelType: "DecisionTreeClassification",
            parameters: ['empty', 1, 1]
        },
        {
            modelName: "2",
            modelType: "DecisionTreeClassification",
            parameters: ['empty', 'empty', 2, 2]
        }
    ],
    numberOfSteps: "1"
}


  for(let [key , value] of Object.entries(val)){
      if(key=='models')
      value.forEach(x => {
          for(let i=0;i<x.parameters.length;i++)
          x.parameters.forEach(y=>{
              if(y=='empty') 
              x.parameters.shift()
          })
      });
  }
  console.log(val.models[0].parameters)
  console.log(val.models[1].parameters)
```